# Is it possible to default Windows 7 start menu to "All Programs"?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible for the Windows 7 start menu to ignore recently opened items list and default into 'All Programs' when you open start menu?

I figured this is a possibility due to the vast amount of changes you can do in the registry but unfortunately after a lot of searching and fiddling I'm afraid this tweak is out of my reach.

I want this done because I never use 'Recently opened Items' when I open the start menu, all I want to access is 'All Programs'.

Example below, hope you get it!

[image]

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I have never tried this program before, so use at your own risk: http://www.intowindows.com/show-all-programs-by-default-in-start-menu-of-windows-710/